# Facebook Conversation Link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get url/link to conversation. based on official document it could be queried using link field.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/conversation

I have both required permission for my app.

The pages_messaging permission

The pages_manage_metadata permission

All i get is

```
            "id": "m_M0wIE2LRCEnc1uq3puhx8tZG4cCq-FvBl1uMnd0HXaETmxzQ1c8jtHHfXzXMtO3qT4F7mmw4RcpNLiGaqYA01Q",
            "created_time": "2021-09-01T16:06:42+0000"
        }
```

CURL

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/{conversation_id}
/messages?access_token={token}&fields=id,created_time,link,message_count,participants,is_subscribed'
```

Comment: That's because this is a field of the conversation object itself, but you are not querying one, you are querying its `messages` edge.

Comment: You are correct i found the issue yesturday but link itself doesn't seem to work. more info on the issue (https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3538611839697303/?join_id=f301c439914a224)